# How to exclude Paths in the Pester configuration?

Tags: powershell, pester

We have a directory structure of modules like the following:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Toolbox.CustomModule1
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Toolbox.CustomModule2
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModuleDownloaded
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModuleDownloadedOther
```

All PowerShell modules starting with 'Toolbox.' are the ones we created and are the only ones that need to be tested with Pester 5. I was hoping it would be possible to use a wildcard:

```
$config = [PesterConfiguration]@{
    Run = @{
        Path = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Toolbox.*"
    }
}
Invoke-Pester -Configuration $config
```

But the above fails because wildcards are not supported in `Path`. Using only `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` fails too due to downloaded modules that are not compatible with Pester 5. So hunting down the documentation I stumbled upon this:

```
$test = [PesterConfiguration]::Default
$test.Filter | Format-List
```

> Tag        : Tags of Describe, Context or It to be run. (System.String[], default: System.String[])
> ExcludeTag : Tags of Describe, Context or It to be excluded from the run. (System.String[], default: System.String[])
> Line       : Filter by file and scriptblock start line, useful to run parsed tests programatically to avoid problems with expanded names. Example: 'C:\tests\file1.Tests.ps1:37' (System.String[],
> default: System.String[])
> FullName   : Full name of test with -like wildcards, joined by dot. Example: '*.describe Get-Item.test1' (System.String[], default: System.String[])

But that doesn't seem to talk about full file names. Is there a simple way to do this (instead of a simple `foreach` but from within the `PesterConfiguration` itself?

Comment: Did you find a workaround in the meantime for this? Another solution you could use temporarily would be to use Get-ChildItem with the wildcard and load those into Path in the configuration object as the Path object accepts arrays of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a [bug in Pester 5.1](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1857). Wildcards are supported and it will be fixed with the new release.